# Snapshot value as int cause crash

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm making a friend request and upon fetching these requests I'm getting an error.

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key xxx

from sending a request works fine([these are the values from sending a request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZU7b.png)):

```
let fromId = (Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
        let toId = self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String

        let senderFriendRef = databaseRef.child("friendship").child(fromId)
        senderFriendRef.updateChildValues([toId : 0])
        let receiverFriendRef = databaseRef.child("friendship").child(toId)
         receiverFriendRef.updateChildValues([fromId : 1])
```

And this is the code that fetches the request. I played around with the  `if (snapshot.value as? Int == 1)` and it might seem this that causes the crash because before I was getting an error saying I can't cast it to an `Int`:

```
if let loggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
    Database.database().reference().child("friendship").child(loggedInUser).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        if (snapshot.value as? Int == 1) {
            let requestId = snapshot.key
            Database.database().reference().child("users").child(requestId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    let person = Person()//model
                    person.setValuesForKeys(dict)
                    person.id = requestId
                    self.friendRequest.append(person)
                    print(self.friendRequest)
                    DispatchQueue.global().async {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
//ending brackets
```

Comment: Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228046/firebase-swift-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key) to the same question you're asking. :-)

Comment: @Kouder okay I tried what he said, but now it's giving me a nil (used option 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ever user `setValuesForKeys` you're just going to get into lots of problems. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689839/swift-3-1-setvaluesforkeys-and-firebase-failing-to-retrive-users) other post helped me fix it.